# Google Maps V3, Map won't display when wrapped in a second div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am a newbie to Google Maps.  I have started with their "Hello World" code, which has the following:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
```

which of course works fine.  But, if I want to wrap their div in another div (so I can set various container styles), the map doesn't display at all:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Apply `width` and `height` to `div`:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%;">
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</div>
```

Inner div's ( `id="map_canvas"` div ) sizes are set by percents. This means inner `div` will be fit to its parent sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the SCRIPT src URL starts with http://. I spent about half a day de-bugging to realize this.

Earlier...

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key....
```

Now

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key....
```

It works on local now...