# How to display a Google Map in a fixed position div?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to put a fixed position map on my webpage. 
I put the a snippet of index.html file below. I have 
a `div` with `id="map-mini"` under a `div` with `class="map-container"`.

I defined the position of the map-container as fixed(the post.css file
is given at the end of the file).

I initialize the map with function given in post.js. However, when I refresh
my webpage, the map is not initialized.

Do you have a suggestion that can solve my problem?

jsfiddle for the given code is as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/N2V8S/2/

Regards.

index.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
        <div class="map-container">
            <div id="map-mini"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
        <div id="post">
            <div class="body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

post.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var map_id  = '#map-mini';
var lat     = 41.04207384890103;
var lng     = 29.0972900390625;
var zoom    = 11;
var myOptions = {
    zoom : zoom,
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map  = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-mini"), myOptions);
});
```

post.css:

```
.map-container{
position: fixed;
border: solid gray 1px;
width: 17%;
height: 80%;
top: 50px;
left: 0.5%;
}
```

Comment: i've noticed too that the map will not be initialized if another div sourrounds my map-div. I suggest that if you put the map-div directly into your <body> it should work

Comment: I don't know if this fixes the problem, but you have a missing `</div>`

Comment: Steven I also tried your suggestions but it didn't solved my problem. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps V3, Map won't display when wrapped in a second div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675075/google-maps-v3-map-wont-display-when-wrapped-in-a-second-div). You have to define the size of the parent elements if you are using percentage sizes.

Comment: @geocodezip, I put your suggestions in my code. However, still I cannot see a map. The updated jsfiddle is as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/N2V8S/3/

Comment: Eventhough, it is not obvious in the jsfiddle, @geocodezip, your suggestion solved my problem at my local computer. Thanks for your help.