# Can somebody help me debug this HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, google-maps

The purpose of my index.php page is to display DB driven content relating to jobs. It is split into a bottom and top half where in the bottom I have a Google Maps v3 API. <strike>Currently I am having some troubles debugging it so that I have both `<div>`'s set to use 50% of the page equally. I would also like them to automatically adjust and maintain the appropriate measurements as the browser is resized.</strike>

<strike>Importantly I am *still* trying to get certain `<td></td>`'s to truncate their text when it is over a given threshold with an ellipses. The best I can manage is where the text wraps but this increases the height of the entire row of the record which makes things look ugly when the browser is resized to a small part of my screen.</strike>

<strike>The major problem I am having is not being able to make the `<div>` that contains my `googleMap` to have 100% height and width. In fact when I specify an inline `style=` of:</strike>

```
<div id="googleMap" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
```

Instead of:

```
<div id="googleMap" style="height:450px;width:100%;">
```

The map does not show at all. I also have similar troubles linking it with the CSS defined style.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps V3, Map won't display when wrapped in a second div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675075/google-maps-v3-map-wont-display-when-wrapped-in-a-second-div)

Comment: I already viewed that, but still have an issue despite working on what was suggested.

Comment: The simple case [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_percentageSizing.html)

Comment: And just to prove there is nothing special about inline css, [this works also](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_percentageSizingA.html), define the sizes of all the parents of all the nested divs in percentages if you want a percentage size map to work. [percentage sized maps](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)

Comment: perhaps you can post your answer then while it is still open (even though it is a duplicate).

Comment: Updated. Have a new (smaller) issue now. Could you help? (See below, and above for complete CSS)

Answer (score 0):

I <strike>have part</strike> resolved it <strike>so this is still unanswered</strike>. There is automatic resizing based on `<div>` height and width percentages, <strike>but now I have the problem that my header in the `bottom_div` is being written over by the `TABLE` in the `top_div`. Here's a screenshot of the problem:</strike>

When troubleshooting in Google chrome I can see by the highlight feature (F12 -> Elements -> then hover over the code relating to elements on the page) that the `top_div` is properly proportioned but that the `TABLE` holding the jobs ignores this and overflow's the `top_div`. I have no idea why but I guess it is to do with the CSS code relating to the `myTable` class. However, I have tried manipulating the "overflow" statement to no success.

Comment: What do you expect? Ask more specifically what your problem is. Your code is quite long, who has the time to read all this and go over it ... for nothing!? No offense here, but it would be helpful if you could narrow it down a little bit. Right now it looks like this: I patched some code together, somehow it doesn't work, pls fix it for me. Pls do a little bit of debugging, narrow your problem down to a particular line and ask a specific question.