# Google Maps div not showing up in JSBin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, jsbin

If I set my width to 500px, I can get the map-canvas div to show up when I click my "get started" button.  If I set my height/width to 100%, it doesn't show up.

I want to be sure my project will load on a mobile device so I don't want to use absolute dimensions.

http://jsbin.com/OpujukIF/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3 | shows no map data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273430/google-maps-api-v3-shows-no-map-data)

Comment: There is an error in the CSS(the comma after 85% has  to be a semicolon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use absolute positioning without a `width | height` value, using `top|left|bottom|right` with `0` set as their values which would result in the `#map-canvas` `div` becoming the size of the containing element `#second` as long as it is set to relative like so:

```
#second {
    position: relative;
}

#map-canvas { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Here is the [updated bin](http://jsbin.com/OpujukIF/7/edit).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Most of the official [map-demos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) use a percentage value for height, and they work pretty good

Comment: @Dr.Molle I just took a quick look through and wasn't able to find one that did, could you reference one?

Comment: The [first one](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple) (pretty much all of them have a "view full screen" that does this).

Comment: @geocodezip I stand corrected, answer edited to remove incorrect information. Thanks!

Comment: It does display the map but now #second inherits the same problem -- No matter what percentage I set this element to, it does not seem to resize the map?

Comment: I just kept giving size the parent elements and eventually learned that the "jumbotron" class was throwing things off.  If I assign this element a size, my problems go away.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See [Mike Williams explaination of percentage sizing from his Google Maps Javascript API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)

```
html {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%; 
}
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map-canvas { 
  height: 85%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your link makes logical sense, however your CSS still results in no map being displayed.

Comment: probably the syntax error in the CSS that Dr Molle pointed out (the , that used to be after 85%)

Comment: Your answer was correct but it was the "jumbotron" class that was throwing things off.  Setting this to have a height and width seems to have fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: There is no jumbotron class in your posted code in the question.

Comment: If it was a problem with a nested div, then it is a duplicate of [Map isn't showing on Google Maps JavaScript API v3 when nested in a div tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349476/map-isnt-showing-on-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-when-nested-in-a-div-tag/16349547#16349547), but I looked at your css and didn't see any.