# Google map marker location issue

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I use Googe Map API.

When I use

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%!important; min-height:400px!important; max-height:100%!important;"></div>
```

the position of the marker is shifted to the right.

But when I use

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:400px!important; min-height:400px!important; max-height:100%!important;"></div>
```

It is showing properly.

I need width 100% and marker to see at the center.
How to do it? I guess  the CSS should play its role but I dont know how to adjust it.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps div not showing up in JSBin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572196/google-maps-div-not-showing-up-in-jsbin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I found it really fast.

```
  <div id="googleMap" style="min-width:400px!important; width:100%!important; min-height:400px!important; max-height:100%!important;">
            </div>
```