# How to display updated coordinates when dragging marker (draggable directions) on the map in google maps javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a web application where the user drag the markers of destination on the screen and the input fields for duration and destination update automatically. I have also put in fields for origin and destination coordinates and I want to update them as well when the on screen markers are dragged. I just don't know where to grab those values from. Here is my code:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 
  Duration: <input id="duration"></div> 
  Distance:  <input id="distance"></input>
  Origin Longitude <input id="origin_longitude"></input>
  Origin Latitude <input id="origin_latitude"></input>
  Destination Longitude <input id="destination_longitude"></input>
  Destination Latitude <input id="destination_latitude"></input>
 <div>



<script type="text/javascript"> 
function initialize() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true
  });

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var request = {
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(51.403650, -1.323252),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(51.403650, -1.323252),
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };


  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
        directions = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
        // Display the distance:
        document.getElementById('distance').value =
          directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + " meters";
        // Display the duration:
        document.getElementById('duration').value =
          directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds";





      })
    } else {
      alert("directions request failed:" + status)
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

   </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this](https://output.jsbin.com/gopoduv/1) example.

Just add

```
marker.addListener('position_changed', printMarkerLocation);
```

Then you can define the function

```
function printMarkerLocation(){
    console.log('Lat: ' + marker.position.lat() + ' Lng:' + marker.position.lng() );}
```

Comment: it gives out undefined 'marker' because markers themselves are not defined in my code.

Comment: thanks @kaskader but i did it by using console.log(directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_address); which poured out the address straight from direction variable and then i geocoded to get coordinates. Thanks for leading me the right direction though.

Comment: You may need custom markers if you want to customize their look

Answer (score 1):

How about getting markers' position during marker drag event?  That should work.

Take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker

There are many event you can listen to.

Comment: Can you give me an example inside my code please, that would really help.

Comment: It looks like you need to suppress default markers and create custom markers so you can listen to their events.  Here is a link that might help http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/map_example_direction_customicon.html

Answer (score 1):

The start and end locations are in the directions response object.  With the current request, you only have one leg, so those will be:

```
document.getElementById('origin_latitude').value = directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat();
document.getElementById('origin_longitude').value =  directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lng();
document.getElementById('destination_latitude').value =  directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lat(); 
document.getElementById('destination_longitude').value =  directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lng();
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true
  });

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var request = {
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(51.403650, -1.323252),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(51.403650, -1.323252),
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };


  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
        directions = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
        // Display the distance:
        document.getElementById('distance').value =
          directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + " meters";
        // Display the duration:
        document.getElementById('duration').value =
          directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds";
        document.getElementById('origin_latitude').value = directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat();
        document.getElementById('origin_longitude').value = directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lng();
        document.getElementById('destination_latitude').value = directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lat();
        document.getElementById('destination_longitude').value = directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lng();
      })
    } else {
      alert("directions request failed:" + status)
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
Duration:
<input id="duration" />Distance:
<input id="distance" />Origin Longitude
<input id="origin_longitude" />Origin Latitude
<input id="origin_latitude" />Destination Longitude
<input id="destination_longitude" />Destination Latitude
<input id="destination_latitude" />
<div>
```