# Google Map rendering but not displaying when wrapped in a div

Tags: html, google-maps

Im loading a google map. The html is:

```
    <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
       html, body, #map-canvas {
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           height: 100%;
    }


</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                                      mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head

<body>

    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

This displays fine. However, if I wrap the map-canvas div in a div, nothing displays!

```
<div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

I can see in firebug the google map html gets rendered but nothing is visible...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps V3, Map won't display when wrapped in a second div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675075/google-maps-v3-map-wont-display-when-wrapped-in-a-second-div)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to display the map with it's height set to 100%, all parent tags must have their height set to 100%.

That being said, the map's parent div height also needs to be 100%.

```
html, body, #map-canvas, #map_container {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
}
```

And the code for the map and the div

```
<div id="map_container">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

After this everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put directly remove outside `<div>` tag

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

put like above